What class of matrices have efficient decompositions into sums of tensor products of Pauli matrices?
Suppose we have an arbitrary matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ where $N=2^n$. Define the Pauli basis as $\{I,X,Y,Z\}$ where,
$
I=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
,\;
X=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\
,\;
Y=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i\\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
,\;
Z=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$
Now suppose that we can decompose $A$ into tensor products of the Pauli basis given by $A=\sum_{l=0}^Lc_lS_l$ where $S_l = \bigotimes_{k=0}^{\log N}\sigma_{r_k}$ for $r_k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, $\, \sigma_{r_k} \in \{I,X,Y,Z\}$ and $c_l$ are complex coefficients. I am specifically interested in efficient decompositions defined by $L=\text{poly}(\log(N))$.
My questions are:

What class of matrices have efficient decompositions of this form? More specifically, suppose I pick a polynomial of order $P$ such that $L=\mathcal{O}(\log(N)^P)$, are there distinct structures that all matrices in this $P$-class must abide by?
If so, how can I learn about how these structures change with $P$?
What area in literature is this topic contained in and what are the keywords that I should be searching for?

